# webservice hosted on iis7.5 has one webmethod invoked every 5 minutes exactly by a "ghost"

Tags: asmx, iis-7.5, event-log

I am a .Net developer encountering behavior of my ASMX webservice on an IIS 7.5 machine for the first time. It is a staging server so I know I am the only one using it.

Strange behavior as follows:

- There are 5 webmethods in this WS meant to be called by web client code
- (to my knowledge) there is no such thing as "default" webmethod for a WS
- each one of the webmethods writes an entry to the Windows event application log upon entry
- the event log entry shows which webmethod called and some other stuff
- if I leave things idle, one of the webmethods gets called every 5 minutes EXACTLY

I've looked briefly at the **rapid-fail protection** feature thinking this might be it. It is currently enabled and set to 5 minutes but the other aspects of it don't seem to apply.

I changed it to DISABLED and restarted IIS but it still behaves in the above strange way. I am confused what this could be...

```
        [WebMethod(Description = "Search TRIM by parsing CF's WebDrawer string for search criteria")]
    public string SearchCF(string trimURL
        , string CFSearchString
        , string CallerPC = "not specified"
        , string RequestorID = "not specified")
    {
#if DEBUG
        string d = String.Format("SearchCF: trimURL={0}, CFSearchString={1}, Identity={2}, CallerPCname={3}, RequestorIdentity={4} "
                                            , trimURL, CFSearchString, GetUserInfo(), CallerPC, RequestorID);
        LogDebuggingInfo(d, 500);
#endif
```

Comment: Is this an ASMX service, or a WCF (.svc)?  Rapid Fail Protection was available in IIS6, BTW, so if this runs fine on IIS6 then RFP is probably not the issue (it probably isn't the issue anyway).

Comment: Sorry, it is ASMX. This is very strange. I've done IISRESET and the same webmethod seems to be invoked by a "ghost" (it is not me). The event log msg announcing the entry to the webmethod comes at 1:35.02 then the same thing again at 1:40:00, 1:45:00, 1:50:00, etc. Weird.

Comment: I'd be willing to guess that the problem is actually in your code somewhere, which means this probably belongs over on StackOverflow.  If you want to post your code over there, I'll take a look at it and see if I can find anything that might help.

Comment: Is it possible this is a monitor to ensure the service is still operational?

Comment: Who is (calling) John Galt('s webmethod)?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a keep-alive agent running somewhere that is pinging your webservice every 5 minutes so the application pool is not recycling? Or maybe this is some setting to keep alive your application pool from within IIS?

Comment: Check the IIS logfiles.  Assuming that logging is enabled check to see what the client IP is that is accessing your service.

Comment: the client IP was the same IP as the server; as if the webmethod in the webservice was running on a timer expiration or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very strange condition described above was solved by installing the standalone version of .Net Framework 4.0 (64bit version) to this server. This was followed by installing ASP.NET 4.0 by running:

```
o   navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 
o   in cmd prompt (run as Administrator) execute:
  • aspnet_regiis.exe –i
  • iisreset 
o   reconfigure both the client site and the site hosting the webservice to run ASP.NET 4.0 (resulted in significant reduction of the number of entries in web.config
```

I checked out the other suggestions above before trying the above sequence which fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer involves applying upgrades. Please see how I fixed this at:

[webservice hosted on iis7.5 has one webmethod invoked every 5 minutes exactly by a "ghost"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615286/webservice-hosted-on-iis7-5-has-one-webmethod-invoked-every-5-minutes-exactly-by)